# getorgchart - click event occuring twice

Tags: javascript, getorgchart

I was experimenting with [getorgchart](http://www.getorgchart.com/) library. It seems to me that the click is registered twice in it on both mouseup and mousedown. I added console.log on click event and observed two prints in the console onClick. Is this a bug and can there be some work around this?

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/GetOrgChart/jzkj2tqc/

I changed this:

```
function clickHandler(sender, args) {
  alert("clicked node.id " + args.node.id);
}
```

to this:

```
function clickHandler(sender, args) {
  console.log("clicked node.id " + args.node.id);
}
```

and came to the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed in the lates version 2.3.2

Comment: Thanks! apparently i was using 2.3.1!